# Preciso achar as duplicatas dentro de um CSV e contá-las

Tags: python, data, csv

estou tentando ler a quantidade de repetições na coluna A e B de um CSV e ver a quantidade de vezes que A e B são iguais como o exemplo abaixo:

input:

```
phillip.allen@enron.com | christi.nicolay@enron.com

robert.badeer@enron.com | monaco@enron.com

phillip.allen@enron.com | yolanda.roberts@enron.com

robert.badeer@enron.com | monaco@enron.com

susan.bailey@enron.com | beth.apollo@enron.com

phillip.allen@enron.com | christi.nicolay@enron.com
```

output:

```
phillip.allen@enron.com | christi.nicolay@enron.com | 2

robert.badeer@enron.com | monaco@enron.com | 2

phillip.allen@enron.com | yolanda.roberts@enron.com | 1

susan.bailey@enron.com | beth.apollo@enron.com | 1
```

```
     import csv
        import collections

        with open(r"grafo.csv") as f:
            csv_data = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",")
            count = collections.Counter()

            for row in csv_data:
                address = row[0]
                count[address] += 1


            for address, nb in count.items():
                if nb > 1:
                    print('{} é um endereço duplicado, visto {} vezes'.format(address, nb))
                else:
                    print('{} é um endereço exclusivo'.format(address))
```

O código a cima foi pego da internet, mas ele só pega a quantidade de repetições de uma unica coluna.

após o CSV ser processado eu quero q ele gere um outro CSV que contenha uma coluna C que mostre a quantidade de repetições

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fabio, utilizando parte do código que você postou, é possível fazer da seguinte forma:

```
import collections

count = collections.Counter()

#Lê o arquivo e pega a quantidade de repetições
with open("grafo.csv") as f:
  for row in f:
    #Removo o \n que é a quebra de linha
    count[row.replace("\n","")] +=1

#Cria um arquivo com a nova coluna de repetições
with open("new_grafo.csv","w") as f:
  #Se precisa trocar o delimitador, seria na linha abaixo
  [f.write(f"{row},{qtd}\n") for row, qtd in count.items()]

#Exibe o novo arquivo no console
with open("new_grafo.csv") as f:
  [print(row.replace("\n","")) for row in f]
```

Esse exemplo trabalha com o delimitador sendo a vírgula, mas é possível alterar essa parte para trabalhar com pipe ou ponto e vírgula, conforme sua necessidade.

---

Caso queira verificar o resultado, é possível executar ele por aqui:

https://repl.it/repls/CurlyWholeFan